# Block Internet Connection through cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, networking

In unix (ubuntu) we have iptables command, using which we can block Internet connection for one user. I want to know if there is any cocoa, carbon API using which a user can block his Internet connection for some time and later can re-connect it.

**Note:** I don't have administrative privileges.

Comment: Do you want to disable WiFi or Ethernet connection via a script?

Comment: If you can share would love to go through it :-)

Comment: I have got one useful answer, not sure why I have been down voted :-(

Comment: hi to people who are voting to close this question. I have found a similar question, related to .net, in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752711/block-internet-connection-for-windows-7-using-c-sharp, which has got some useful answer to, and is not closed, so I am not sure why this question is voted to be closed. Please clarify. Again I think that it can bring some more useful answer if not closed.

Comment: Because that example is running on Windows 7 which every user is also guarantee to be admin. On a Unix system, if you user wants to block internet, just disable the Wi-Fi or unplug the Ethernet cable. Simply.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X 10.7 and later supports [PF](http://openbsd.org/faq/pf/index.html), an OpenBSD packet filter, which is almost certainly the right way to go about this.

The command-line interface to manage rules is [`pfctl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pfctl.8.html). Likely you'll need to invoke it as root, using [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html). Here's an answer which describes an [NSTask-like wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475533/893113) which may help you.

PF does appear to support rules based on UIDs (look for the `user` parameter on the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/pf.conf.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/pf.conf)). If you need help configuring PF to do what you want, post at [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [apple.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanx a lot for your useful answer.. will surely try it :-)

Comment: I have one more question.. suppose a user is not having administrative privileges, and still he wants to block Internet Connection, only for his account then how can he do it?

Comment: I think a helper program with admin privileges is the only way that would work.

Comment: ok...once again thanx :-)